# Integral expansions

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

How to find the leadi­ng behaviour of
$$\int_0^{\pi^2/2}\int_0^{\pi^2/2} e^{x \cos(\sqrt{q+s})}\,dq\,ds$$ as x ten­ds to infinity?If we ­consider the first in­tegral w.r.t dq and t­ry Laplace method, is­ it right to take q=0­ as the maximum? Plea­se help to proceed

Comment: Given $s \in (0,\pi^2/2)$, $f(q)=\sqrt{q+s}$ will change monotonically from $\sqrt{s}$ to $\sqrt{s+\pi^2/2}<\pi$ as $q$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi^2/2$. Thus the argument to the cosine is between $0$ and $\pi$, so that the cosine is decreasing as a function of $q$. So using the Laplace method for the $dq$ integration will indeed use $q=0$. Thankfully, integrating preserves the "asymptoticness" of an asymptotic expansion, so all you need to do is to carry out this Laplace method calculation and then integrate it in $ds$.

Comment: (Of course I don't guarantee that this is the optimal way to do it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first perform the substitution $$y=s+t, z= s-t$$ in order to obtain
$$I = \int_0^{\pi^2/2} \!dy\,y e^{x \cos\sqrt y} + \int_{\pi^2/2}^{\pi^2}\!dy\, (\pi^2-y)e^{x \cos\sqrt y}.$$

As $\cos \sqrt y$ is negative on the interval $y \in[\pi^2/2,\pi^2]$ the second integral is exponentially small for $x\to \infty$ and the dominant contribution comes from the first integral.

In the first integral, $\cos \sqrt y$ obtains its maximum at $y=0$. So employing Laplace's method, we obtain the leading order
$$I \sim \int_0^\infty \!dy\,y e^{x (1-y/2)} =\frac{4 e^{x}}{x^2}$$

Comment: Remark: this is not the "quadratic" Laplace method as you have when the derivative vanishes at the point in question, because $\cos(\sqrt{y})$ has a nonzero derivative at its maximum.